# How can I change my username in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am a newbie on Ask Ubuntu and as I used my gmail to sign up I'm getting a random usename or user id.

Is it possible to change the username?

Answer (score 0):

For you, go to this link and change the Display Name

https://askubuntu.com/users/edit/current